# MS-Excel Graph Api how to check if an excel sheet is empty

Tags: excel, microsoft-graph-api

I have been using the get range api link(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/range-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)   to check if an excel sheet is empty. Below is the api

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/items/{{ITEM_ID}}/workbook/worksheets/:worksheet_id/usedrange`

The response is same in these two condition

1: sheet is empty

2: when the sheet has just one element at A1.

Sample respons

```
    "addressLocal": "sample!A1",
    "columnCount": 1,
    "columnIndex": 0,
    "rowCount": 1
```

When used with valuesOnly=true

```
    "addressLocal": "Sheet5!A1",
    "columnCount": 1,
    "cellCount": 1,
    "columnHidden": false,
    "rowHidden": false,
    "numberFormat": [
        [
            "General"
        ]
    ],
    "columnIndex": 0,
    "text": [
        [
            ""
        ]
    ],
    "formulas": [
        [
            ""
        ]
    ],
    "formulasLocal": [
        [
            ""
        ]
    ],
    "formulasR1C1": [
        [
            ""
        ]
    ],
    "hidden": false,
    "rowCount": 1,
    "rowIndex": 0,
    "valueTypes": [
        [
            "Empty"
        ]
    ],
    "values": [
        [
            ""
        ]
    ]
}
```

Even when the sheet is empty the response has **rowCount : 1 and columnCount : 1** as the response properties.
Is there any other way to track whether the sheet is empty.

Answer (score 0):

You can try call the endpoint with parameter `valuesOnly`.

In the request URL you may provide optional parameter `valuesOnly` and in that case cells without values should be ignored. Cells with formatting assigned to them won't be ignored.

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/items/{id}/workbook/worksheets/{id|name}/usedRange(valuesOnly=true)
```

Resources:

[UsedRange - function parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/worksheet-usedrange?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#function-parameters)

Comment: Doesn't help I just created a new sheet and used the Api  with (/usedRange(valuesOnly=true). I have pasted the response in my above question. It seems to have  "" as default values.

Comment: @sacDahal I'm afraid that there is no easy way. Is it acceptable for you to call /usedRange(valuesOnly=true) and if cellCount == 1 then check the value in the cell? If the value is "" then you can assume that sheet is empty.